# omniture how to access s_code.js generator

Tags: javascript, web-analytics, adobe-analytics

I've create an account at developer.omniture.com and adobe.com. But I wasted my time because to access s_code.js generator I should login to https://my.omniture.com/login/. How to create test account there?

Answer (score 2):

Only registered users are permitted to login to the SiteCatalyst interface. You will want to either contact the client you are doing work for and request a login, or you can contact the omniture sales team to request a demo.